# Render a DIB image in a window by using Directx

Tags: visual-c++, directx

I am new in VC++. I have created a window using WinApi.Now I want to render a DIB image in created window by using DirectX. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:
1. Create a texture.
2. Load DIB data into the texture.
3. Render the texture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am new in VC++. please give me some ideas or code to how load a image from memory.Thanks in advance.

Comment: HOW to load DIB data into the texture. plaese help me